# My simple PowerQuery finishes, but Excel continue to lag even afterwards for minutes

Tags: excel, powerquery, m

I'll run a custom PowerQuery in Excel 365, the results are returned and displayed as a table on the worksheet, and all is well -- until I go to continue to use Excel. **Excel continues to lag for about 5 minutes after the results are returned!**

I've looked through some PowerQuery performance solutions, but all seem to address slow query performance. The queries perform within expectations -- whereas **I'm looking for advice to combat Excel locking up for a while after results are returned.**

This happens with a variety of queries using different datasources -- not just one or a few. Since the lag is occurring AFTER results are returned, I'm looking for generic potential solutions.

Most of my code uses datasources like the current workbook's tables, a file folder, and perhaps tables located within other Excel files.

Answer (score 0):

I've never encountered this before working with power query.  Are you experiencing the same symptoms if you load similar connections to a mostly empty workbook?  If you are the issue may be with your install or available resources on your workstation.  If not, there may be an issue with the existing code you have in a workbook (ie: inefficient code that you have triggered by a pivot table update event).